# Is it possible to set a property as Enum but get a custom string value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums

I'd like to set a property as an Enum so only certain values can be stored but when getting the property, I'd like to get a string value.

So for example, store an Enum of `Orange1` but get "Orange 1".

Is this possible? If not, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: With a TypeConverter or a second backing field that you set to `[Enum].ToString()`. It depends on what you mean with *store*. If you need to serialize a class, you can make a custom converter when you serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a Description attribute. Let's create an Enum that looks like this:

```
Public Enum Fruit
    <Description("Orange 1")>
    Orange1 = 1
    <Description("Orange2")>
    Orange2 = 2
    <Description("Apple 1")>
    Apple1 = 3
End Enum
```

Now in a Module, add the following extension method:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function GetEnumDescription(item As [Enum]) As String
    Return If(item.GetType().
                   GetField(item.ToString()).
                   GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False).
                   Cast(Of DescriptionAttribute)().
                   FirstOrDefault()?.Description, String.Empty)
End Function
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
Dim f As Fruit = Fruit.Orange1
Console.WriteLine(f.GetEnumDescription())   ' Prints "Orange 1"
```

Comment: I'd probably be inclinded to return `item.ToString()` if there's no `DescriptionAttribute`, which means that you can simply not apply the attribute to any fields that don't need spaces.

Comment: [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?552547) is another way of using the `DescriptionAttribute`. In this case, you'd use the slightly more verbose `New EnumDescriptor(Of Fruit)(f).Description`. The biggest advantage of these classes is that they make it very easy to bind an `Enum` to a `ComboBox` or the like.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I'll create an extension method which returns `Item.ToString` and replace any _ with spaces.